# "this computer has been scheduled to go to sleep" when none is set

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, power-management

Simple question- My mac regularly & seemingly randomly tells me it has been scheduled to go to sleep automatically- usually (I *think*) right after I wake it up. I have no schedule for automatic sleep set up in preferences.

When this happens I just shrug and cancel the countdown box but it is annoying. Is there any way to see what is triggering this message and fix it?

Comment: I assume you've gone to System Preferences/Energy Saver and checked there?

Comment: Yes, nothing sticks out when checking `pmset -g` either (though I don't know that area as well). This has persisted from sierra through my upgrade to high sierra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using iDrive that might be the culprit.

Comment: Can someone explain this answer? I actually have iDrive and a Mac exhibiting the same symptoms, but I've gone through the iDrive settings and anything that automatically powers off/sleeps the Mac is disabled.

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue as well. I found two potential answers:

This one suggests resetting PRAM and the SMC:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7702633

However, the second one mentions iDrive (as did a previous answer here). I did, in fact, switch to iDrive about a month ago, and believe the dialog box began appearing after installing it:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8304128?page=2

The above thread refers to a response from iDrive support which suggests un-checking the "wake from sleep" setting (it is apparently checked by default; mine was). For me, the issue was completely resolved by making this change; it has been 4 months since I changed the setting with zero recurrence. Make sure you don't miss the "do you want to save changes" dialog after changing it; iDrive has a way of making macOS feel like Windows.

[image: iDrive Setting to change]

Comment: In my case idrive was the issue, and i stopped using it entirely for unrelated reasons. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Mac Mini running High Sierra and have it scheduled to wake up at 2am every day to do backups.  The problem was that it didn't seem to be sleeping again afterward (as it should after 10 minutes of inactivity according to my Energy Saver preferences).  I could tell this because the light on the front of the Mini was on, not pulsating.  It seems as if only the display was sleeping even though I unchecked "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off".

I tried also setting a scheduled sleep time of 2:15am in the Energy Saver preferences, but that didn't help, plus I got a dialog when I turned on the computer at 7am saying that it was about to sleep in 9 minutes.

I solved the problem by disabling the scheduled sleep time, extending the sleep timeout to 20 minutes, and adding the following line to my crontab (edit the crontab with "crontab -e"):

15 2 * * * pmset sleepnow

The command makes the computer sleep, and the cron job is set to run at 2:15am.  I don't know if it was necessary to extend the Energy Saver sleep period, but I did this to make sure the cron job would execute before the Energy Saver preferences kicked in, and so far it is working for me.

Edit:

I found that my Late 2014 Mac Mini would then go into "safe sleep" after some time, and it wouldn't wake up according to the schedule.  Entering the following two commands at the Terminal fixes this by extending the safe-sleep delay to 1 day:

1) "sudo pmset -a standbydelay 86400"

2) "sudo pmset -a autopoweroffdelay 86400"

(see here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6625408)